# SonarQube C++ build-wrapper produce empty build-wrapper-dump.json

Tags: c++, sonarqube

I'm using sonarQube C/C++ on WIN10 machine on a vxworks (arm) cross compile project.
After running:

```
build-wrapper-win-x86-64 --out-dir bw_output make  MyProject.make
```

Build succeeded, but I get empty build-wrapper-dump.json file.

looking at the build-wrapper.log file I see:

```
process created with pid: 25256
image path name: <C:\WindRiver_6.9\gnu\4.3.3-vxworks-6.9\x86-win32\bin\ccarm.exe>
command line: <ccarm   ...long line... MwInterfaceService.cpp  >
working directory: <CommonLib\>
isWow64: 1
skipping process C:\WindRiver_6.9\gnu\4.3.3-vxworks-6.9\x86-win32\bin\ccarm.exe with pid: 25256
```

Is there a way to make build-wrapper to fill build-wrapper-dump.json file correctly?

thanks,
Mr. G

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube C/C++ supports `WindRiver` `diab` arm compiler on the older versions.

There is a recent effort to support `WindRiver` `gnu` / `llvm` arm compilers with the recent **build-wrapper** versions.

- `gnu` The empty json file problem is already resolved with `build-wrapper >=v6.51`. We verified that it works as expected with the updated version.  You need to upgrade your SonarQube installation. [CPP-4783](https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/browse/CPP-4783)
- `llvm` It is still an open issue. [CPP-4844](https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/browse/CPP-4844)

Comment: is the point of this answer to suggest to use diab instead?

Comment: Yes, but it's only a partial solution. 
Recent vxworks packages does only support llvm compiler.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35327371)